# como puedo ejecutar el comando de un text-area en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

este es mi text area si escribo console.log('hola') en el solo quiero que me aparezca hola en la pantalla como puedo hacerlo

```html
<textarea id="textareaUno" >
console.log('hola')
  </textarea>

<buton>ejecutar</button>
```

Resultado = hola

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es una instancia de una nueva función a partir del valor obtenido del textarea.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function ejecutar(){
  //Obtener el valor del comando a convertir
  const fnVal = document.getElementById('textareaUno').value;
  // Convertimos el valor en una funcion.
  // Puede dar errores si lo se controla, por ejemplo si la funcion/comando no existe
  const fn =   new Function(fnVal);
  // Llamamos a la funcion final.
  fn()
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaUno" >
console.log('hola')
  </textarea>

<buton onclick="ejecutar()">ejecutar</button>
```